# How to export from sql server table to multiple csv files in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a simple clients table in sql server that contains 2 columns - **client name and city**. In Azure Data Factory, how can I export this table to multiple csv files that each file will contain only a list of clients from the same city, which will be the name of the file

I already tried, and succeeded, to split it to different files using **lookup and foreach**, but the data remains unfiltered by the city

any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to follow the below flow chart:

1. LookUp Activity : Query : Select distinct city from table
2. For each activity
   Input : `@activity('LookUp').output.value`
   a) Copy activity
   i) Source : Dynamic Query  Select * from t1 where city=@item().City

This should generate separate files for each country as needed

Steps:
1)
[image]

2. The batch job can be any nbr of parallel executions
   [image]
3. 

[image]

4. Create a parameterised dataset:
   [image]

[image]

5)
[image]

Result: I have 2 different Entities, so 2 files are generated.

Input :

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: didnt work... I got this error - Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed

Comment: @Golan : Please see the above edited answer. That should help you in the set up of the pipeline.
Note : Country is equivalent to Entity in example

Comment: Nandan , Thank you so much for your detailed answer - it's flawless and perfect , thank you !

Comment: @Golan Glad I could be of help :) hope you can accept it as answer as this can be beneficial to other community members as well.

Comment: Hello @Nandan . is it possible to add a filter to the source query in the copy data activity . for example - Copy activity i) Source : Dynamic Query Select * from t1 where State=@item().State AND I want to add to the query a  filter by city = 'London'

Comment: Hello @Golan , you can reciprocate any SQL query in the copy data activity as you need :)
Because ideally that query is getting executed in the SQL server itself

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) to achieve that easily.

I made an example for you. I create a table as source, export this table to multiple csv files that each file will contain only a list of clients from the same city, which will be the name of the file.

**Data Flow Source**:
[image]

**Data Flow Sink settings:** File name options: as data in column and use auto mapping.
[image]

**Check the output files and data in it:**
[image]

[image]

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer  that is also a way to do it .

Comment: @Golan You're are welcome! I think using Data Flow is much easier, just choose the way you like best. If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you and merry Christmas!