# Creating a multiple CSV files from a Single Table in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have a Single SQL Table named an Employee Table. In Employee Table there are the following columns 1. ID, 2. Designation, 3. Salary, 4 Joining Date .. etc.

Now let say there are 200 records in this Employee Table, with 10 different designations of Employee. Now, I want to create a CSV file of this table using Azure Data Factory, based on(filter by) designations, i.e 10 CSV files(bcoz there are 10 different designations) should generate and store this in the storage account in Azure.
Kindly guide me in this.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to follow the below flow chart:

LookUp Activity : Query : Select distinct designations from table
For each activity
Input : @activity('LookUp').output.value a) Copy activity i) Source : Dynamic Query Select * from t1 where designation=@item().designation
This should generate separate files for each Designation as needed

For more details:
[How to export from sql server table to multiple csv files in Azure Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65422356/how-to-export-from-sql-server-table-to-multiple-csv-files-in-azure-data-factory/65422585#65422585)

Comment: The second example (City) worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey @AshishShelar, Can you please mark it as answer as it may benefit other community members as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Another way: use Data Flow, set `Key partition type` and choose `Designation` as partition column at Source. Then choose `Pattern` as File name option and use `employee[n].csv` as file name.

Details:

1.set `Key partition type` and choose `Designation` as partition column at Source.
[image]

2.choose `Pattern` as File name option and use `employee[n].csv` as file name
[image]

[image]